# Find dates and change format in C#

Tags: c#, regex, date

I have a text file with different data. Now I need to replace multiple things in the file, before I can use the data correctly. I have replaced texts with Regex. But now I need to change dates. But I can't figure out how to do that.

The dates look like this: `"utc": "2017-10-02 19:55:00.205263000 Z"`
And I want to get this result for all the occurences of this date format:
`"utc": "2017-10-02 19:55:00"`

I tried to use following code:

```
string pattern = @"{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff Z}";
string replacement = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(theInputTextFile, replacement);
```

Is it not possible to use date formats with regular expressions. Or did I make a mistake in my code?

[I used the information from here, for the date formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: As you suspect the RegEx engine is unaware that d/m/y etc are date/time indicators - they are for formatting only.  Naively `\d{4}-\d{2}` matches `4digits-2digits` ...  For complete strictness match, `TryParseExact()` then re-format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you can give Regex.Replace method a delegate so that you can convert its format. 
Examine the example in this page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

A code sample is below, which finds dates that are formatted as you wrote in the question and replaces with the new format:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = " dasd arew 2017-03-11 12:25:56.345 Z 2017-03-11 12:25:56.345 Z das tfgwe 2017-03-11 12:25:56.345 Z";
        string pattern = @"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\sZ";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        var res = r.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(ConvertDateFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }

    static string ConvertDateFormat(Match m)
    {
        var mydate = DateTime.Parse(m.Value);
        return mydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    }

}
```

Comment: This assumes you have matched correctly to begin with.

Comment: @MattJohnson you're right. I assumed so. I added the correct regex pattern to my code sample now

Answer (score 0):

> Is it not possible to use date formats with regular expressions

Correct.  It is not possible.  Regular expressions and date format/parsing tokens are two unrelated concepts.  You would need to match for specific text.  The internals of a date parser might use a regular expression to achieve such a goal, but one can't simply pass `yyyy` to a `Regex` class and expect it to find `2017`.  You would have to use something like `\d{4}` for that, and it will catch any four consecutive numbers.

Also note that date format tokens are case sensitive, and you've mixed up minutes (`mm`)  with months (`MM`) and use 12-hour hours (`hh`) instead of 24-hour hours (`HH`) without an am/pm indicator (`tt`)  - not that it would matter here anyway since you pass into a regex.